# Download images and save them but dont want them in the gallery

Tags: android, image, download

I have a chat app and I need to save the images that the user sends receives.  For the images the user sends I am saving it to an image folder like so

```
private void imageDownload(final String url){

    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(url)
            .into(getTarget(url));

}

//target to save
private static Target getTarget(final String url){
    Target target = new Target(){

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    File heyJudeFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Hey Jude");
                    if (!heyJudeFile.exists()){
                        heyJudeFile.mkdirs();
                    }

                            localProfilePictureAdress = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Hey Jude" + "/" + url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

                    File file = new File(localProfilePictureAdress);
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                        ostream.flush();
                        ostream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };
    return target;
}
```

But for images the user receives I want to save the images but I do not want the images to be viewable in the gallery how does that work?

Thanks

Comment: Just add `.` as prefix to folder or file name.

Comment: change the file extension.simple.

Comment: Thanks and what is the difference between this and caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below method to hide media from gallery

```
/* To Hide media file in gallery  */ 
public void createNoMedia(String myDir){

    File noMediaFile = new File(myDir, ".nomedia");
    if (!noMediaFile.exists()) {
        try { 
            noMediaFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
}

/* To use this */
dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/MyImages/";
File newDir = new File(dir);
newDir.mkdirs();
createNoMedia(dir);
```

and in `manifest.xml`
You also need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by editing name of your file and adding an unknown format like ".example" then it doesn't appear in gallery